Whirlpool oven won't turn gas back on reliably
When we turn the oven, the element heats up and glows bright orange, but the gas doesn't start flowing. However, we've found if we play with the burners on top - e.g. turning one on and off - it will decide to turn the gas on after all and will start warming the oven. Once the oven is up to temp it shuts off, but then when it decides it's time to turn on again, same thing - only the element comes on and glows until we mess with the range, and then the gas will start. I've waited minutes for the gas to turn back on and then fussed with the range a bit and it kicks right in, so I don't think it's just coincidence.
We have replaced the element (albeit with a well-rated off-brand unit from Amazon) and that didn't help.
I just can't rationalize why the burners would have any impact here. I feel like it's a control issue and that engaging the burners makes it go back through some control sequence and finally realize the igniter is ready, but maybe it's a slight change in gas pressure or electrical draw that finally makes it engage?
I have not checked the gas valve yet, as I just ran across that when looking into this, but it is operating correctly otherwise. Do I just need to review that? (I guess even if it is just that, it might helps others to see this still).
Whirlpool model WFG505M0BS2
Gas oven sometimes stops heating seems like the same situation, and looks like it was the igniter - do I just need to get a better igniter? Or check the temperature sensor I guess?

Gas valve will open when it gets the signal from the thermocouple that the ignition is ready – clean the thermocouple or replace it
